# Verify ES256 CSR

Tags: elliptic-curves

I created a CSR using ES256(ecdsa).  I want to verify it.
How do I verify a CSR using ES256?

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBCzCBsAIBADAfMQ0wCwYDVQQDDAR0ZXN0MQ4wDAYDVQQEDAVvdGhlcjBZMBMG
ByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABAJA4hRnXwSydejyKYgB349JX/MKueTl6qei
Ge7s6Leny05ze4oQWaLS7qsQfJGt/8RPCoymGypU12iakhIUfE+gLzAtBgkqhkiG
9w0BCQ4xIDAeMA0GBGgAAAAMBWF0dHIwMA0GBGgAAQAMBWF0dHIyMBMGByqGSM49
AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0EAFgmtbPwkCaNLvvhNoWJt07IXVQDGwiefI76RNR/vAyOB
E6EfYtWB9naTDWCRqqvG9T23MEJu9MVqAgjfLc5ARw==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Comment: You might want to decode the Base64 and ASN.1 out of it by pasting it at https://lapo.it/asn1js to [this](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBCzCBsAIBADAfMQ0wCwYDVQQDDAR0ZXN0MQ4wDAYDVQQEDAVvdGhlcjBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABAJA4hRnXwSydejyKYgB349JX_MKueTl6qeiGe7s6Leny05ze4oQWaLS7qsQfJGt_8RPCoymGypU12iakhIUfE-gLzAtBgkqhkiG9w0BCQ4xIDAeMA0GBGgAAAAMBWF0dHIwMA0GBGgAAQAMBWF0dHIyMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0EAFgmtbPwkCaNLvvhNoWJt07IXVQDGwiefI76RNR_vAyOBE6EfYtWB9naTDWCRqqvG9T23MEJu9MVqAgjfLc5ARw) effect. What about `man req` ? Perhaps, `openssl req -text -noout -verify -in CSR.csr`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is *invalid* as the signature is not DER encoded, it's not an X9.62 signature as such. See TR-03111 section 5.2. What you have is a "plain signature format", i.e. just a statically sized r & s concatenated.

Comment: I compared it with the CSR openssl made ASN1  and the signature type is different.  also bitstring is formatted different also.